# Synchronize attribute changes in Python

Tags: python

I've subclassed a Python `dict`, roughly like this:

```
class JSONDict(dict):
    @property 
    def __json__(self):
        return json.dumps(self)

    @property
    def __path__(self):
        return os.path.join(settings.BASE_PATH, self.entity, 'settings.json')

    def __init__(self, entity, *args, **kwargs):
        dict.__init__(self)
        self.entity = entity

        try:
            os.utime(self.__path__, None)
        except OSError:
            open(self.__path__, 'a').close()

        self.__file__ = open(self.__path__, 'r+')
        self.__to_python__()

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        self.__file__.close()

    def __to_json__(self):
        self.__file__.seek(0)
        self.__file__.write(self.__json__)
        self.__file__.flush()
        self.__file__.truncate()

    def __to_python__(self):
        if os.path.getsize(self.__path__):
            self.__file__.seek(0)
            dict.clear(self)
            dict.update(self, json.load(self.__file__))
        else:
            self.clear()

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        self.__to_python__()
        return dict.__getitem__(self, key)

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        dict.__setitem__(self, key, value)
        self.__to_json__()

    def update(self, data):
        dict.update(self, data)
        self.__to_json__()

    def clear(self):
        dict.clear(self)
        self.update(__default__)
        self['nar'] = self.nar
```

I can use this quite fine, e.g.:

```
>>> with JSONDict('entity-id') as json_info:
...    json_info['setting_a'] = 'foo'
```

However, there's an interesting problem when it comes to lists. When I modify the list directly, e.g `json_info['setting_b'].append('bar')`, the JSON file doesn't get updated. I was certain that overriding `__setitem__` and `__getitem__` would cover all item access, but clearly that's not the case. What should I override to get this work?

UPDATE:

Having read the first answers, I felt that this question wasn't formulated in a right way. The right question would be, how to effectively observe dict attribute changes in order to be able to update the JSON accordingly? Should it be done via proxy/descriptor objects, metaclasses, or is there a more generic way?

Comment: The `list` is just a `list`.

Comment: Note, you really shouldn't define your own double-underscore methods. Just call them `to_json`, `to_python` etc.

Comment: The point is that the **reference** of the list does not change, so the `JSONDict` us *unaware* of changes that happen to its children (and descendants in general). Updates of children are not reported to the parents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Willem Van Onsem mentions, mutating a `list` doesn't update the dict itself - you are NOT calling `JSONDict.__setitem__` when doing `json_info['some_list'].append(whatever)` -  and actually you'll have the very same problem for just any mutable object.

The technical solution here would be to make `__getitem__` return a proxy wrapping the actual object and `JSONDict` instance and overriding `__setattr__` to detect any change on the proxied object, ie:

```
class Proxy(object):
    def __init__(self, jsdict, key, obj):
        # avoids triggering `__setattr__`
        self.__dict__["__jsdict"] = jsdict
        self.__dict__["__key"] = key
        self.__dict__["__obj"] = obj

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        setattr(self.__obj, name, value)
        self.__jsdict[self.__key] = self.__obj

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return getattr(self.__obj, name)


class JSONDict(dict):
    # ...

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        self.__to_python__()
        return Proxy(self, key, dict.__getitem__(self, key))
```

Now this will still not work for lists (or other containers), so you also need to implement `Proxy.__setitem__`. And since lists contained in your `JSONDict` can themselve contain mutable objects, you need to make sure that you also proxy whatever containers in you JSONDict contain...

Oh and yes, whatever attribute is looked up on a proxied object should be proxied too so that `json_info['some_list'][42].foo.baaz = 'wtf'` works as expected.

Ok I think you get the point now: making this work in a generic, reliable way is going to be difficult. Not to mention performances hit...

You'd probably have a more reliable solution just saving to file on `__exit__` and / or providing an explicit `save()` method for the end user. This would also save (no pun intended) on disk writes...